# is the function $1/\sqrt{x}$ uniformly continuous?

Tags: real-analysis

Is it correct/ true to say that since $f=1/\sqrt{x}$ is continuous on the interval $(0,1)$, so f is uniformly continuous?

Comment: No unbounded function on a bounded region is uniformly continuous.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. A function that is continuous on a compact set is uniformly continuous (cf Theorem 4.19 in Rudin's Principles).

The idea of uniform continuity is that for every $\varepsilon$ you can pick a $\delta$ so that *independent* of where you go in the domain
\begin{equation}
  |x_0 - x_1| < \delta  \Rightarrow  |f(x_0) - f(x_1)| < \varepsilon.
\end{equation}

Now, because for your function you won't be able to do this. For any fixed $\delta$ if you go close enough to zero then $|f(x_0) - f(x_1)| > \varepsilon$.

Comment: Simply having the derivative get arbitrarily steep near $0$ doesn't preclude uniform continuity on $(0,1)$. Consider the function $g(x)=\sqrt[3]{x}$, for example.

Comment: You're right. I've corrected the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

$1/\sqrt x$ is not uniformly continuous on the interval $(0,1)$.

If $f$ is continuous on the **closed**  interval $[a,b]$ then it is uniformly continuous on the interval $[a,b]$

Answer (score 1):

No.
Otherwise it can be extended continuously to the end points 0 & 1.
But the given function is unbounded near 0.
Thus, it is impossible to extend this map continuously towards 0. Which is contradiction.